# Can I Use The Facebook Name And Logo On A Login Button?

Tags: facebook, icons, facebook-login, branding

I'm using the facebook-unity-sdk and have integrated facebook login for easy user authentication. This seems to be encouraged. However, I am at the point where I am designing my login button, specifically to log into facebook, with permissions requests and what not. When designing my button, am I allowed to use the facebook f logo or the word facebook or anything similar?

If so, where can I find the logos or fonts that would be appropriate for me to use?

I found the following site, but it appears unclear for my circumstance.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/branding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website you linked to (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/branding) already provides lot of information. The global message is:

**Don't use facebook brand names or logo for anything else than linking to facebook**

This other website should provide you with the logos you can use: https://en.facebookbrand.com/assets/f-logo and gives you the info you were looking for, basically:

**Don't modify the facebook logo**

So you can use the facebook name and logo as long as you don't modify them and that the usage is not confusing (it really redirects to facebook applications). Hope this helps

Comment: I find it unclear whether or not I can say "Log in with Facebook required" in my app's store description. I don't think it implies partnership but I feel they never give enough examples with these things to clear up all the ambiguity around their policies.

Comment: I think you can say it if it is true. Worse case, Google will ask you to change the description